# (Objective-c) Make the app remember what view it was on

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Hey I'm working on a view based application with many views and I would like it to remember what view it was on when the app was quitted so when you start the app again if will go right to the view you left of at.

Any help please  :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the Three20 TTNavigator tool as part of the Three20 tools - it is what the Facebook application uses to do exactly what you've said.

Comment: Do you know where I can get the tools?

Comment: Google "Three20" :) It's on github.

Comment: Sure - can you set this question as answered then?